# Span background image of parent only across children

Tags: css, background-image

I want to have the background image of the `#parent` element show only on its children and not on the gaps between its children. The background image of the body must be visible in between the children of `#parent.`

HTML

```html
    <div id='parent'>
        <div> TEXT </div>
        <div> TEXT </div>
        <div> TEXT </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
body{
   background-image: url('image1') repeat;
}

#parent{
    background-image: url('image2') repeat;  
}

#parent div{
    margin-top:50px;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Note: I don't know if this is possible or not. If you can suggest another way to achieve the same effect that would also be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: If your child divs would have fixed heights, you could set for all the same background image with another position to start from.

Comment: Sven Bieders solution is the only one, not requiring javascript to solve this. Though you need a fixed height for the child divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the CSS background-attachment Property

The following might work depending on how your layout is built:

```css
body{
   background-image: url('http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/Patterns1-06.png');
}

#parent div{
    background: url('http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/busytown_.PNG');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    color: slategray;
}
```

The useful property is `background-attachment`.

**Demo Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/de8NZ/

**Reference:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment

Answer (score 0):

I just made a fiddle of Sven Bieder solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/BcLAW/

CSS

```css
body{
background-image: url('http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/Patterns1-06.png');
}
#parent div{
background:url('http://imgs.ir/imgs/201308/busytown_.PNG');
display: inline-block;
padding: 25px;
margin-right: 11px;
color: slategray;
}
#parent div:nth-child(1) {
background-position: -26px -61px;
}
#parent div:nth-child(2) {
background-position: -117px -61px;
 }
parent div:nth-child(3) {
background-position: -208px -61px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id='parent'>
    <div> TEXT </div>
    <div> TEXT </div>
    <div> TEXT </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good solution for a known number of divs. In my case I have a unknown number of them and they contain variable text. I don't think this can be done with css only.